# Need a regex to match everything that does not contain a '?'

Tags: regex

I want a regex with this rule: everything what not contains `?`

I tried this but doesn't works:

```
^(?!\?)$
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To match any string that does not have a `?` in it you can use:

```
^[^?]*$
```

[**see it**](http://rubular.com/r/CPmrGNDx9j)

You can also use a negative lookahead as:

```
^(?!.*\?).*$
```

[**See it**](http://rubular.com/r/rq27VMIf2y)

Answer (score 2):

```
 [^?]*
```

(zero or more not-?). You might need to escape the ? with a \ depending on your regex impementation. If your regex doesn't match agains the whole string by default, then

```
 ^[^?]*$
```

This will also match the empty string. If you don't want that, replace * with +